# .replace backslashes along with chars in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm stuck on the`.replace` function. 
I have a gallery, previewing thumbnails through this URL standard:

```
/uploads/admin/mcith/mcith_1157936397041.jpg
```

I want the URLs to be like this:

```
/uploads/admin/1157936397041.jpg
```

removing the `mcith/mcith` part.

I've done a small `.replace` script and got pretty close, but got stuck with the slashes and underscores.

Here's what I got:

```
v = $(this).attr("src").replace(/mcith/g,'');
alert(v);
```

The alert prints this:

```
/uploads/admin//_1157936397041.jpg
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: FYI, `.replace` is a basic JavaScript function, not jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some characters have a special meaning inside those regular expressions. These characters need to be escaped by preceding them with a backslash

```
v = $(this).attr("src").replace(/mcith\/mcith_/g,''); alert(v);
```

Comment: I blinked and it worked! thank you guys for great help and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape forward slashes by preceding it with a backslash:

```
v = $(this).attr("src").replace(/uploads\/admin\/mcith\/mcith_/g,'uploads/admin/'); alert(v);
```

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/AEay2/

Comment: That explains a whole lot for me, thank you very much. but there is also an underscore that needs removal, but only for the image part of the string.
v = $(this).attr("src").replace(/mcith\/mcith/g,'').replace(/_/g, ''); alert(v);

this replaced all the underscores in the url, since the thumbs are generated with the mcith_ prefix, it needs to recognize only this. any ideas? :)
Thanks again.

Comment: please see my answer ... it includes removing the specific underscore

Comment: sure, just added the trailing underscore to the regex pattern. i updated the code in my answer.